# Docker node build - babel preset and deep module errors

Tags: node.js, docker, webpack, babeljs

After resolving several extra babel presets required (to what my npm scripts built), then an `unknown plugin "add-module-exports" in /node_modules/react-dropzone/.babelrc`, I'm now encountered a requirement to `npm rebuild node-sass --force`

Also, webpack is taking a long time build, 3-4min.

I have a feeling either my node_module folder or the environment isnt setup properly here. Is my current setup doing something silly that I'm missing?

.babelrc

```
{
  "compact": false,
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "es2015-loose",
    "stage-2",
    "stage-1",
    "stage-0",
    "react"
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
    }
  }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:7.7.3

RUN npm install -g pm2 babel-cli

# Useful for reloading npm install if package json changed
ADD package.json /tmp/package.json
RUN cd /tmp && npm install
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app && cp -a /tmp/node_modules /usr/src/app

COPY . /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ADD .babelrc server.js index.js /usr/src/app/

CMD ["pm2", "start", "./index.js", "--no-daemon"]
EXPOSE 2020
```

docker-compose.yml

```
doc:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "2020:2020"
  volumes:
    - .:/usr/src/app/
    - /usr/src/app/node_modules
```

./index.js

```
require('babel-register');
require('./server.js');
```

./server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

const isDeveloping = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const PORT = isDeveloping ? 2020 : 2020; // process.env.PORT - docker?
const app = express();


if (isDeveloping) {
  let webpack = require('webpack');
  let webpackMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
  let webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware');
  let config = require('./webpack.prod.config.js');
  const compiler = webpack(config);
  const middleware = webpackMiddleware(compiler, {
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
    noInfo: true,
    quiet: false,
    lazy: false,
    watchOptions: {
     aggregateTimeout: 300,
     poll: true
   },
   stats: {
    colors: true,
   }
 });

const bundlePath = path.join(__dirname, './dist/index.html');

app.use(middleware);
app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));
app.get('*', function response(req, res) {
res.write(middleware.fileSystem.readFileSync(bundlePath));
res.end();
});

 } else {
   console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)
   const staticPath = path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
   app.use(express.static(staticPath));
 }

 app.listen(PORT)
 console.log('Open up http://localhost:' + PORT);
```

Answer (score 0):

you're configuration is fine, from what you show, i think.

> now encountered a requirement to npm rebuild node-sass --force

do you have a `.dockerignore` file set up in your project folder? if not, add one and include `node_modules` in that file. it's the same format as a `.gitignore`.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file

my thought is that you are copying your host operating system's `node_modules` folder into the Docker image by mistake. the `npm install` process is not replacing it because it sees the package is already there.

by adding the `.dockerignore` and telling it not to copy the node_modules folder, you'll force the docker image to install the modules. this way, the `node-sass` modules (which required native build) will be compiled correctly.

> webpack is taking a long time build, 3-4min.

you're on a mac? Docker has a known issue with hard drive access being many times slower than native drive access, or even Docker on linux.

Windows isn't as bad as mac, but it's still worse than linux.

there's not much you can do about this... almost nothing, unfortunately. you're already using a volume for the node_modules folder... you can try adding a volume to the temp folder where webpack is building things, but you'll only get about a 25% performance boost from that.